# C: I need to extract some data from a text file and it keeps erroring me with segmetation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have written this code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Values{
    char timestamp[21];
    int temperature;
};

char *readString(char out[], FILE *fp){// Reading and storing the input values, out = the string that this func returns
    int ch, i;
    while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp)))
        if(ch == '"') break;

    for(i=0;EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp));++i){
        if(ch == '"') break;
        out[i] = ch;
    }
    out[i]='\0';
    return out;
}

void printValues(struct Values values[], int i){ //just a printing method, for printing the values, i = the amount of values I have
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<i; j++){
        puts(values[j].timestamp);
    }
}

int main(void){ //The beginning of the programm, what did you expect?
    struct Values values[10];
    FILE *file = fopen("hum1.txt", "r" );
    int i=0; //the number of every stored value

    if (file != NULL ){
        char tempString [25];
        while(*readString(tempString, file)){ //if the readStrinf outputs "" == "/0" (end of FILE)
            strcpy(values[i].timestamp, tempString);
            i++;
        }
        fclose(file);
    }

    printValues(values, i);

    return 0;
}
```

My testing txt file is working fine. **Testing txt:**

```
{"Something": "Something else", "Something else else"}
{"Hey": "Is anyone there?"}
{"Something else else else"}
```

But when I try to read the data from the "right" txt file it keeps returning me a segmetation fault

The **"right" txt** file is something like that:

```
{"2014-02-13T06:20:00": "93", "2014-02-13T13:50:00": "66", "2014-02-13T06:00:00": "91"}
{"2014-02-14T04:50:00": "87", "2014-02-14T09:50:00": "87", "2014-02-14T12:20:00": "81"}
```

With multiple lines (in this format) and more data in it

Could anyone help me? I don't know why this is happening,

Thank you in advance.

**Also. I forgot to mention that the programm 
1.reads a file named: hum1.txt. 
Then looks for the first ' " ' and till the next ' " ' it stores the data between in a struct array**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct Values values[10];
```

You allocate space for 10 values.

> {"2014-02-13T06:20:00": "93", "2014-02-13T13:50:00": "66", "2014-02-13T06:00:00": "91"}
>    {"2014-02-14T04:50:00": "87", "2014-02-14T09:50:00": "87", "2014-02-14T12:20:00": "81"}

Your file has 12 values.

The first thing you should do when debugging code like this is add checks to see if any accesses are out of bounds. That would have immediately caught the problem.

Comment: OT, `char tempString [25]` should be `char tempString [21]` as the declaration of struct, right ?

Comment: Because there are many data that I need to store in memory (from the txt file), I have to make it dynamic, with malloc? Am I thinking correctly?